# Loading themed material2 for angular with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material2

I am trying to use a themed material2 for angular in a webpack project.

Now I want to include the compiled scss-file in the index.html via like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="somewhat-themed-material.css">
```

I do not have the somewhat-themed-material.css, I only have somewhat-themed-material.scss

How can I get webpack to compile this scss file and offer it up in the dist-folder for me to load it from index.html?

PS: Or am I thinking horribly wrong? Basically what I am trying to do is a global.scss which is always loaded from index.html

Answer (score 0):

Install  **'sass-loader'** and update in the **module.rules** in the webpack.common.js file.

```
{
          test: /\.scss$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }
```

more info https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-include-Material